# Are UIPageViewController and NSURLConnection the correct classes for loading vc's in the background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process, uipageviewcontroller

I have a dining menu app that scrapes the data from a website and redisplays it in a mobile format, displayed below:

[image]

If the user swipes left and right, the app will show the previous/next meal (ex. if current meal is lunch, swiping left will show dinner. If current is dinner, next will be breakast of following day).

I'm trying to come up with a more efficient way of switching between menus.  With my current implementation, each menu is a separate view controller.

When someone swipes right, it calls:

```
-(void)swipeleft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
    //swipes to next meal
    MealType curMeal = currentMenu.type;
    int newMeal = [MenuLoader MealAfterMeal:curMeal];

    MenuTableController *newMenu = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
    newMenu.currentMeal = newMeal;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newMenu animated:YES];
}
```

When each view controller is created (including the first), it loads the menu in a background thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        MenuLoader *ml = [[MenuLoader alloc] init];
        currentMenu = [ml mealForType:_currentMeal Specificity:[self summaryPreference]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            ...
        });
    });
```

Inside the `mealForType:Specificity:` call, I parse 2 separate web pages through `NSURL`, and combine the information from both sites:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *pageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Some of the optimizations I'm hoping to make are:

- Preloading adjacent menus in another thread to reduce loading time when someone swipes
- If someone swipes forward and then back, it should show the already loaded menu. Right now, it makes a fresh call to the server and reloads everything.
- Right now, if someone swipes multiple times in a row before any of the menus finish loading, the app tries processing all of the server calls at once and this slows down the loading time.  If someone does swipe repeatedly, the current menu should take precedence, and possibly the other calls should be terminated.

It sounds like a big overhaul of my design, so I was wondering if there was a better approach to loading menus than what I currently implemented. The classes I had in mind were UIPageViewController and NSURLConnection, but I'm not sure if those are the best choices.

Answer (score 1):

`UIPageViewController` it's a viable solution for easier handling of horizontal scroll and it will provide a better user experience, but for having the best user experience you'll have to handle the server request in a proper manner.

From my point of view there are two cases that must be considered:

I. Do you want to have up do date data (like what's available at the precise moment when the user is on the current screen)

II. Do you want to have relative up do date data (last update was xxx minutes ago).

For both cases I would suggest the following:

1. Create a core data where you'll store all the data retrieved from the server side. The controllers/screens will load the data only from core data. You can decide when to remove old entries using timestamps.
2. Let's say you have the following UI display 1 - screen from left side, 2 - screen displayed now, 3 - screen from the right side. At app start, load the data in the following order 2, 3, 1, in this way the data from the displayed screen will be loaded first, then the data on the other screens.
3. For the server request I would suggest to use a `NSOperationQueue` with `NSOperation`, this will give you the possibility to cancel/order the server requests. Also it will be easier to have background request (rule of thumb: all long processing tasks should be done on background threads)

Now for the particular cases:

**Case I.**

If the user scrolls to a different screen, cancel all the existing operations in the `NSOperationQueue` and add new ones as in point 2. above. This will ensure the up to date requests. When the data is received & stored in core data, you can display it.

**Case II.**

If the user scrolls to a different screen, display the existing data from the db (if no data available for that screen show a progress indicator, it should happen only at first launch), check if there is an operation for the current screen in queue, if there is do nothing, if there isn't, create one an add it to queue. When the data is received and updated in db, display the new data.

Comment: Do I have to pass the NSOperationQueue instance to each view controller?

Comment: No, you should use the singleton pattern for the operation queue.

Comment: So, if I call `[NSOperationQueue new]` within each vc, does that access the same instance? Or am I supposed to be using a different function.

Comment: `new` will create a new instance of `NSOperationQueue`. You'll have to create your own singleton class that will create a single instance of `NSOperationQueue` that can be access trough the app. Check singleton pattern (little google will help)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been able to implement these changes.  I haven't used Core Data before, do you think it's worth learning just for this?

Comment: @Mahir I think `CoreData` has a big role in iOS programming, so I strongly suggest that you learn it, at least the basic concepts and the simple part.

Comment: 2 more questions: will core data be stored offline for the user, or does the app make a server call to core data every time the app reopens?  If it's the latter, will there be a noticeable performance improvement to calling the server for the raw html data?

Comment: Secondly, how am I to store the data initially? Is there a way to have core data daily parse the web data and store it in a db automatically, or does it need to update it through the app?

Comment: @Mahir Core data is stored offline, every time you do a server call and parse the response data  you should also store it in core data. This also answers to your  second question, you have to update the core data trough the app. Think of core data as your app data base, it can be accessed only by your app and that's it, and your app decides how to updated the content of the databse.